# Porque o input não aparece no resultado da function php

Tags: php, input, funções

Criei uma função (estou fazendo umas experiências) para gerar input, textarea, select, etc, através de function.
Porém o resultado é parcial. Não tem erro na função, mas só o que é texto (sem estar no input) aparece e o input é mostrado no código fonte, mas na página mesmo, não vem nada.

Código:

```
    // type (textarea ou o type do input) | name | id | required (required ou vazio) | placeholder | Titulo que vem antes do input | conteudo é o echo do BD (pode ser um array quando para select | onlyread (onlyread ou vazio) | checked ou selected ou vazio | options (array com opções para select ou opções para radio e check | primeira serve para primeira opção em selects

function geraInput($type, $name, $id, $required, $place, $titulo, $conteudo, $onlyread, $checked, $options, $primeira){

$inp = '<div class="env_inputs">
        <span class="tit_inputs">'.$titulo.'</span>
    <input type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" id="'.$id.'" '.$required.' '.$place.' value="'.$conteudo.'" '.$onlyread.'></div>';

return $inp;
}
```

Na chamada da função:

```
echo geraInput("text", "teste1", "teste", "", "", "Teste:", $resumo, "", "", "", "");
```

No código fonte:

```
<div class="env_inputs">
    <span class="tit_inputs">Teste:</span>
    <input type="text" name="teste1" id="teste"   value="<p>Casa nova, com 2 dormitorios, banheiro, sala de jantar e estar, 2 vagas de garagem, cozinha, &aacute;rea de servi&ccedil;o, churrasqueira.&nbsp;</p>
<p>Pronta para finaciar e morar !!</p>">
</div>
```

Na tela:

```
Teste:
```

Comment: Sua variável `$conteúdo` tem elemento html `<p><\p>` e por isso tah bugando seu elemento `<input>`

Comment: Então, obrigado pela resposta, primeiramente.
Coloquei um strip_tags na variável que preenche o value e não mudou o resultado na tela.
No código fonte sumiram os <p>, mas não alterou o resultado em tela.

Comment: Tentou em diferentes navegadores? Testei aqui no chrome 49 e funfou normal, inclusive o html que você postou.

Comment: Qual browser está usando para testar? Qual `doctype` está definido no HTML? Qual o conteúdo do css `env_inputs`? Há algum outro estilo css para elementos `<input>` ?

Comment: Putz!
Cara, obrigado.
O problema não estava no código. Era uma div com id teste que estava em outro include e tinha um css com diplay none.
Foi falha minha. Desculpe e obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente a função assim:

```
function geraInput($type, $name, $id, $required, $place, $titulo, $conteudo, $onlyread, $checked, $options, $primeira){

$inp = '<div class="env_inputs">
        <span class="tit_inputs">'.$titulo.'</span>
    <input type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" id="'.$id.'" '.$required.' '.$place.' value="'.htmlentities($conteudo).'" '.$onlyread.'></div>';

return $inp;
}
```

Adicionei o 'html_encode()' para evitar que os elementos do value possam bugar o input. Teste e passe feedback!

Comment: Não funcionou amigão.
Essa função dá erro - não achei documentação no manual php.
Tentei com htmlentities, htmlspecialchars... Nada faz o input aparecer na tela...

Comment: Desculpe, equivoco meu! seria a 'htmlentities' mesmo, mas seu problema realmente não é esse! Testei aqui em passou normal seu código.